# Understanding timing constraints

Tags: fpga, vhdl, serial, constraints, sdc

I don't want an introductory text on timing constraints, nor an application note, an user manual, a webinar. I read them all, already, many times. The concept behind timing constraints is very easy. Still, when I have to code them in a sdc file I can't get through it. I have to spend several days trying and failing to make the Quartus software accept my design. And I know for sure that many other FPGA designers are suffering like me.

Somebody please stop this agony!

Let's try with an example. Consider the following top entity:

```
entity top is
    generic (
        W : positive := 8
    ) port (
        ser_data_in  : in  std_logic;                      -- Serial data in   
        ser_bclk_in  : in  std_logic;                      -- Bit clock in     
        ser_fclk_in  : in  std_logic;                      -- Frame clock in   
        par_data_in  : in  std_logic_vector(W-1 downto 0); -- Parallel data in 
        par_wclk_in  : in  std_logic;                      -- Word clock in    
        ser_data_out : out std_logic;                      -- Serial data out  
        ser_bclk_out : out std_logic;                      -- Bit clock out    
        ser_fclk_out : out std_logic;                      -- Frame clock out  
        par_data_out : out std_logic_vector(W-1 downto 0); -- Parallel data out
        par_wclk_out : out std_logic                       -- Word clock out   
    );
end entity;
```

Serial data is transmitted at DDR, clocked by the bit clock (frequency = F), which is center-aligned. Serial data comes also with a frame clock, which is edge-aligned with the first serial bit (frequency = F/W).
Parallel data is SDR, clocked by the word clock (frequency = F/W), which is edge-aligned.

I won't enter into SERDES details, let's imagine that I have a simple shift register that shifts with ser_bclk_in and transfers its data to another register every rising edge of ser_fclk_in. Deserialized data operates somehow with parallel input data and the result is output to ser_data_out and par_data_out. Naturally, the SERDES at the output is specular to the input.

My question is: for a given maximum skew between data and clocks, how do I constrain such a design?
Since I have already all the clocks I need, can I successfully constrain this design without using PLLs?
It is necessary to declare multicycle paths? If so, why?

P.S. I am still willing to read more about the topic, therefore, if you know any uncommonly clear text about timing constraints, please share it too :)

Comment: Last time I used Quartus (many years ago, on version 9) there was a special OpenLDI "Megafunction" block for LVDS SerDes. Apparently on the Altera Cyclone III, only certain locations support LVDS. Have you looked at this megafunction?

Comment: Yes I did, and not without success. Megafunctions allow also to instantiate PLLs and constrain inputs automatically.My question is more general, and I wanted the answer to this question to be a learning reference. I can't believe this can't be explained clearly once for all.

Comment: It all depends on your frequency and how accurate your incoming clock is, is you are creating a DDR interface at low frequency, then you don't need any PLL or much of timing constrains, you just need to identify your clocks and the tool will take care of the rest, but if you have a high speed clock then you must use PLL, the rest of your question is too generic to answer without knowing more about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer by choosing Tools > TimeQuest Timing Analyzer.
2. Choose File > New SDC file. The SDC editor opens.
3. Type the following code into the editor:

   ```
   create_clock -period 20.000 -name osc_clk osc_clk
   derive_pll_clocks
   derive_clock_uncertainty
   ```
4. Save this file as my_first_fpga_top.sdc (see Figure 1–38).